# Kernel Panic on Raspberry Pi 2 on the 2. boot

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, kernel

This happens to me every time:
 
I prepare a fresh microSD card on my Mac, put it inside my Raspberry Pi 2. 
It boots fine.
I shut it down and boot again (or Reboot).
It fails with a Kernel Panic.
Why and how can I avoid it??
It happened to me both with the latest Raspbian version and also with Retropie.
And it keeps happening every single time, even if I just boot with a screen and LAN connected.
If I boot without screen and just LAN, it's the same thing. I can SSH into it and after the first reboot it's gone.
SD Card: Toshiba SDXC 64GB (new)
OS: Raspbian Jessie, Retropie v3.6
Pi model: Raspberry Pi 2
[image: error message]

**Update:
I ordered 2 SanDisk Ultra's with 16GB each, I will inform you as soon as I'll get them. But I am pretty sure it was the card which was bad. (64GB, SDXC, Toshiba - 3 negatively influencing factors lol)**
**Update 2:
See my answer: The SanDisk Ultra works perfectly, so it really was the card that just DOESN'T WORK - DON'T BUY A TOSHIBA SDXC FOR A PI! :-)**
 **- solved :) -**

Comment: Could you edit your post and include a photo of the kernel panic messages?

Comment: How are you poewering the Pi? Have you tried a new SD card? How are you shutting down the Pi?

Comment: Could be a problem with the SD card

Comment: @steve-robillard I am powering it through an iPhone 6 wall adapter. It should provide enough power I think.. (?) I am shutting it down via "sudo shutdown -h now". Okay I will return the SD card tomorrow.... It's an SDXC 64 GB Toshiba card.

Comment: I would check the verified SD card list http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards. While some 64GbB cards work the foundation has not suggested anything bigger than 32GB.

Comment: Thank you very much Steve. I am going to try to return my micro SD card tomorrow and get 2 16GB SanDisk cards. I realised that I don't need much storage for my projects anyway.

Comment: That does look like a problem in accessing the root file-system BTW - the very top line (partway through the report for CPU0 I presume as the other three fall over subsequently) is reporting a `panic` in the `mount_block_root` function and the very last line is advising that the system could not sync the same file-system - so it will be marked dirty and would of needed an `fsck` on restart anyhow...

Comment: SlySven I'm quite new into Linux so I am not sure what the mount_block_root does. But would you confirm that the SD card might be the issue?

Comment: I'm going to get the SanDisk Ultra with 8 or 16GB twice, that is listed on the elinux site 

Comment: I'm supporting @SlySven here. He's right on the corruption part. If you want to learn Linux and fix something in the process, check the volume using `fsck` manually. If you're as lazy as me, go download a fresh copy of Raspbian and flash it again.

Comment: Guess the 64GB card will be useful for something else - maybe it is just TOO big for some uses (e.g. my new mobile 'phone will only take a maximum card size of 32GB). Let us know if a different card fixed it (write an answer yourself - you are allowed to!) Assuming that you have a PC system, what does THAT do if you try and read the card *after crashing*?  Be aware that a Windows PC is likely to only see the first VFAT partition (which is not the, now faulty, one) but if you have a Linux type PC it will be able to see ALL the partitions on the card (and `fsck` the corrupted ext2/3/4 ones!)

Comment: @SlySven hey Sven, I'm sorry I can't read the card after such a crash as it didn't happen to me anymore with my new cards and I already returned the old one :)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE / SOLUTION:**
 
So, I got 2 SanDisk Ultra's with 16GB each in the mail today. 
Thank you all again for your answers.
It was clear to me that somehow, my Pi seemed to destroy the file system on the 64GB Toshiba card (or it destroyed itself?? ), but as I couldn't figure out what it was, I tried to return the card and changed it for 2x16GB (yes I know that's only 32gb @ the same price but I don't care :D). 

So, I flashed the cards with different images and both cards work like a charm and - most importantly because this was the problem - survive all the reboots that I need to do :)
(remember with the other card, it got stuck at the 1. Reboot / 2. Boot).
 
I can really recommend the SanDisk Ultra MicroSD! (~8€ for 16GB)
For anyone using a mac: "PiFiller" - a small AppleScript App - provides a quick and easy way to flash (micro)SD cards for raspberrys :-)